# AutoCompleteBox Click on item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using `AutoCompleteBox`:

```
<my:AutoCompleteBox Grid.Column="1" Name="SearchTextBox" Height="23" Width="240"  
                            Populating="SearchTextDidChange" FilterMode="None" SelectionChanged="SearchBoxDidSelectItem" />
```

And this is the methods:

```
private void SearchTextDidChange(object sender,System.Windows.Controls.PopulatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTextBox.Text))
    {
        google.GetSuggestFromGoogle(SearchTextBox.Text);
    }
}

private void SearchBoxDidSelectItem(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteBox item = (AutoCompleteBox)sender;
    string searchString = (string)item.SearchText;
    this.SendSearchRequest(searchString);
}
```

And the issue is that i want to get the selected string when the user press itand to made the search, but the function "SearchBoxDidSelectItem" called every time the user enter new char to the TextBox. Any idea how to fix it? How can i get the clicked on item method?